# (Discord.py) Add delay to dm messages with on_guild_join event

Tags: python, events, discord, discord.py

I own a big discord server and after the release of my bot everyone added it within seconds. One of the feature of my bot was to dm the owner saying "Thanks for inviting me, type -help to check the commands". There was a problem behind this: the bot sent like 30 messages to different owners in 5 seconds and my bot ended up by getting banned by discord cause of spam. After a few tries I understood that a dm can be sent each 15 seconds in order to not get banned.

How can I add a cooldown each dm? For example if someone adds it, the bot sends the owner a dm then another owner invites the bot before 15 seconds but he will receive the dm after the cooldown.
Command I used:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await guild.owner.send("Thanks for inviting the bot! Type -help to check the commands!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You can use `asyncio.sleep` for waiting

```py
import asyncio 

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    await asyncio.sleep(time_seconds)
    await guild.owner.send("Thanks for inviting the bot! Type -help to check the commands!")
```

Comment: please fix indentation.

Comment: Okay sorry new here

Comment: @OlauPlaRichart this command will just wait 15 seconds after being added then send a dm to the owner. But this is not what I am willing to do. Cause if someone else adds the bot at the same time the 2 owners will receive the message at the same time after 15 seconds. Let me know if you understood

Comment: Nope I didn't sorry could you detail some more?

Comment: Idk how to explain it better also my english is pretty bad. Imagine that a owner invites the bot and he gets dmed but after 2 seconds another owner invites the bot he can't be dmed as 15 seconds didn't pass between the first and the second invite. He will be dmed once 15 seconds passed and so on. Is it clearear?

Comment: To clarify @Cusihko he meants to say if the difference between invites is 2 seconds, the bot will send the first message after 15 seconds and then the second one just 2 seconds after the sending the first one. So this answer only adds 15 seconds delay to all the messages resulting in same behaviour as original

Answer (score 0):

based on your requirements you want the bot to wait 15 seconds until sending message to the owner. You can do so by having a global variable named `last_dm_sent_time` which stores at what date and time was last dm sent. and inside the `on_guild_join` event you can wait until 15 seconds have passed

Add this to start of your file just after imports

```py
import datetime
import asyncio

last_dm_sent_time = datetime.datetime.now()
TIME_DIFFERENCE = 15  # Replace with how many seconds before sending new messages
```

now in your function:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    global last_dm_sent_time
    while datetime.datetime.now() <= abs(last_dm_sent_time+datetime.timedelta(seconds=TIME_DIFFERENCE)):  # Wait Until TIME_DIFFERENCE seconds have passed from last message sent time
        asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait before rechecking while loop condition (Helps in reducing errors)
    last_dm_sent_time = datetime.datetime.now()  # Reset the timer for other instanced of the same function call.
    await guild.owner.send("Thanks for inviting the bot! Type -help to check the commands!")
```

**Note:** The solution does exactly what OP asked for but if for example 4 users invited it at the same time it will take 1 minute to send to all users because it will wait for 15 seconds for each one. This is not a bug but just for making others understand.

Here is an alternative implementation that you can have:

```py
import asyncio

TIME_DIFFERENCE = 15

global message_queue = []

async def message_sender():
    while True:
        asyncio.sleep(TIME_DIFFERENCE)
        if len(message_queue) > 0:
            await message_queue.pop(0)
```

and for the above here is the `on_guild_join` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    message_queue.append(guild.owner.send("Thanks for inviting the bot! Type -help to check the commands!"))
```

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński How? the global variable last_dm_sent should make it work